# svg color does not change in scoped css stenciljs

Tags: tailwind-css, stenciljs

I am trying to change the color of the svg in document.addclass method to customize the color.When i added the color in class after compilation it didn't reflect it.

For example: I have mentioned below in component css file

`.thumbs-up { color: rgb(55 65 81); }`

Then in component typescript file, trying to render this class when user clicks on the icon.

The rendered html looks like

`.thumbs-up.sc-ai12z-chat { color: #374151; }`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, hope you will find new knowledge here. You can help us answering your question, by adding a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with the [< >] button in the editor. It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.